# A conflict exists with definition _bounces in namespace internal Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, adobe-flash-cs3

hi, I am trying to create a game on Flash CS3 Action Script and keep getting  error on line 13-15 saying that A conflict exists with definition _bounces in namespace internal, A conflict exists with definition _highscore in namespace internal, and A conflict exists with definition _ball in namespace internal??? and help please

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip
    import flash.text.TextField
    import flash.events.Event
    import flash.events.MouseEvent

    public class DocumentMain extends MovieClip
    {
        public const Gravity:Number = 2;
        public const Bounce_Factor:Number = 0.8;

        public var _bounces:TextField;
        public var _highscore:TextField;
        public var _ball:Ball;

        public var _vx:Number;
        public var _vy:Number;


        public function DocumentMain():void
        {
            _vx = 0;
            _vy = 0;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
        }

        private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            //gravitate the ball
            _vy += Gravity;
            //move the ball
            _ball.x += _vx;
            _ball.y += _vy;
            //check stage boundaries for collision
            checkBoundaryCollision();
        }
        private function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //Hit the ball if it has been clicked
        }

        private function checkBoundaryCollision():void
        {
            var left:Number;
            var right:Number;
            var bottom:Number;
            var Top:Number;
            left = _ball.x -(_ball.width / 2);
            right = _ball.x +(_ball.width / 2);
            bottom = _ball.y +(_ball.height / 2);
            top = _ball.y + (_ball.height / 2);

            if (left < 0 && _vx < 0)
            {
                _ball.x = _ball.width/2;
                _vx *= -1;
            }
            else if (right > stage.stageWidth && _vx > 0)
            {
                _ball.x = stage.stageWidth -(_ball.width /2);
                _vx *= -1;
            }
            if (top < 0 && _vy < 0)
            {
                _ball.y = _ball.height / 2;
                _vy *= -1;
                }
            else if (bottom > stage.stageHeight && _vy > 0)
            {
                _ball.y =stage.stageHeight -(_ball.height / 2);
                _vy *=Bounce_Factor;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a file/class named TextField in the same directory/package as the class above?

Comment: how do i check if i do? not to sure

Comment: I bet you have selected in publishing properties (for ActionScript 3.0 settings) to automaticaly name stage instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "Advanced ActionScript 3.0 Settings" - I'm using CS5.5 and don't have CS3 (but it should be same) via File -> Publish Settings -> ActionScript Settings and there uncheck the "Automatically declare stage instances" (this is default setting)

or do not define them in the class.

[Detailed description of Error 1151 and resolution](http://styleanderror.net/2008/09/11/error-1151-a-conflict-exists-with-definition-mymc-in-namespace-internal/)

Answer (score 0):

probably you have duplicated definitions.

like For example:

```
 var _bounces:TextField;
```